# python subprocess doesn't work in TeamCity build step FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, teamcity

My build log says:

```
[10:43:14]  [Step 1/1] subprocess.Popen(cmd)
[10:43:14]  [Step 1/1] File "c:\python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
[10:43:14]  [Step 1/1] restore_signals, start_new_session)
[10:43:14]  [Step 1/1] File "c:\python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1114, in _execute_child
[10:43:14]  [Step 1/1] startupinfo)
[10:43:14]  [Step 1/1] FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Code:

```
cmd = r'curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -u username:pw --data @{filename} https://(jira-base-url)/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber -H "Accept-Content: application/json"'.format(filename=filename)
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

I've connected to the server, and ran the same python script on the server in the same directory as team city working dir, and it works. So the file does exists. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The path for the file you are you trying to find, needs to be relative to TeamCity build working directory, OR ideally, the full path on the server. As the file exists, the likely cause will be the path/value you have specified for '**filename**' in your code ...

```
.format(filename=filename)
```